# register_taxonomy is not displaying/appearing in admin pages or post types in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, admin, taxonomy

I have used register_taxonomy function to create a taxonomy in WordPress but it is not displaying in admin side but it is displaying Quick Edit section.

Can anyone help to figure out this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding this parameter for register_taxonomy and it worked.

'show_in_rest'       => true,